# Removing quotes from a string / an alternative to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, escaping

I have dropDown element which takes the options in the format

```
     ctrlOptions:{0:'String',1:'int'}
```

in addition to simple data types i have user defined data types hence i want to populate this dynamicaly . so i used a loop and concatenation

```
    var dropDown = "{"
for(var i=0;i<dataTypesList.length;i++){
 if(i == dataTypesList.length-1){
  dropDown = dropDown + i + ":" + "'" + dataTypesList[i].Name + "'}";
 }else{
  dropDown = dropDown + i + ":" + "'" +  dataTypesList[i].Name+ "'" + ",";
 }}
```

This yields be the options in required format but along with quotes around it like

ctrlOptions:"{0:'String',1:'int'}"

i want to remove the double quotes i tried with replace it diesnt seem to help. how can i achieve this can i use any other way.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to create is an object & not a string.

So wildly guessing from your code, that the input **dataTypesList** looks something like this:

```
dataTypesList = [{Name:'String'}, {Name:'int'}]
```

You should use :

```
var dropDown = {};

for(var i=0;i<dataTypesList.length;i++)

  dropDown[i] = dataTypesList[i].Name;
```

And then Output is an object :

```
 {0: "String", 1: "int"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.parse to convert the options string from string json to object json:

Using your code (slightly modified):

```
var dropDown = "{"
for(var i = 0; i < dataTypesList.length; i++)
{
 if(i === dataTypesList.length - 1)
 {
  dropDown += i + ":'" + dataTypesList[i].Name + "'}";
 }
  else
 {
  dropDown += i + ":'" +  dataTypesList[i].Name + "',";
 }
}


// later...
ctrlOptions: JSON.parse(dropDown);
```

Verify your target browsers are compatible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

If not, there are some libraries compatible with older browsers that do the same thing.  JSON2 is recommended by the author for out-of-date browsers: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js